# Stop Bash from expanding a wildcard before command execution

Tags: linux, bash, busybox

I have a boot script `/init` that starts a Linux embedded system. In there I have a function that counts partitions from an SD-Card

```
get_number_of_partitions () { ls ${SDCARD_DEV}p* 2> /dev/null | wc -l; }
```

It works with some busybox versions, but not all versions. The expectation is to count partitions, like `/dev/mmcblk0p1  /dev/mmcblk0p2`. When I traced down, I find that with non-working cases, the `p*` is expanded to `proc` before the `ls` command. Resulting in counting 1 instance of `${SDCARD_DEV}` + about 100 items from `proc` children.

I also tried: `ls ${SDCARD_DEV}"p*"` which gave the same result.

Comment: What is the value of `$SDCARD_DEV`?

Comment: $SDCARD_DEV looks like `/dev/mmcblk0`

Comment: Stopping expansion wouldn't have helped, as `ls` itself will not perform the expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of that this would happen is if `${SDCARD_DEV}` ends with whitespace, e.g.

```
SDCARD_DEV="/dev/ "
```

As a result, the command being executed is

```
ls /dev/ p*
```

instead of

```
ls /dev/p*
```

Disabling the wildcard expansion won't solve this problem. First of all, `ls` doesn't do wildcard expansion itself, it depends on the shell expanding the wildcard before invoking it. Second, `ls` would still see these as two separate arguments, it wouldn't interpret `p*` as being files to match inside `/dev`.

Ideally you should figure out why the space is being added to the variable in the first place, and fix that. If not, you can remove it before using the variable:

```
SDCARD_DEV="$(sed 's/ *$//' <<< "$SDCARD_DEV")"
```